# CMake disable -std=c++11 flag for C files

Tags: c++, c++11, build, cmake

I'm trying to build [bkchaind](https://github.com/bkchain/bkchaind). One build option is to use cmake, so I installed it with Homebrew (OSX 10.9.1). When I do `cmake`, though, I get:

```
[  2%] Building C object json-rpc-cpp/src/jsonrpc/CMakeFiles/jsonrpcStatic.dir/connectors/mongoose.c.o
error: invalid argument '-std=c++11' not allowed with 'C/ObjC'
```

I am none too sure why `cmake` would try to pass a C++-specific compiler option to a C/ObjC file. If I comment out this line in the main `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-std=c++11)
```

then it no longer passes the flag to *any* file. However, the C++ files do need it. How do I get `cmake` to include the flag for C++ files, but not for C files?

Comment: Perhaps look in CMakeLists.txt file(s) if the flags is set somewhere?

Comment: @Anycorn: Hah yep I did just that, and updated the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` to set c++ specific flags:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

Comment: No, you and the OP have broken picture icons! :)

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot more sense.  Who in their right mind would use carp as a profile pic.

Answer (score 1):

This type of thing can be done explicitly without any dependence on the specific format of a compiler's flags:

```
target_compile_features(someTargetName PUBLIC cxx_std_14)
```

`target_compile_features` can also do this more implicitly I think, by requesting particular language features that are only found in the desired version of the language.

Another way is to set a target property:

```
set_property(TARGET server PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

Or one may set `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD`, whose value is used as the default value for `CXX_STANDARD` on targets, and then allow targets to inherit that value implicitly.

(Here I'm using the 2014 standard, but of course one may specify 11 or some other value.)