# Mixing C and C++ sources in cmake

Tags: c++, c, c++11, cmake

I am trying to compile a C and C++ source codes.
Currently I am using c++0x standard for C++ by adding this line to the cmake file `add_definitions(-std=c++0x)`.

During the compilation, I get the following warning: `cc1: warning: command line option ‘-std=c++11’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]` and this error: `error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode` referred to a for loop in the c code.

I am wondering how can I set a standard for c code in the cmake file.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818497/cmake-disable-std-c11-flag-for-c-files?rq=1

Comment: Look at the updated answer, I forgot that with the previous answer you would overwrite the already set flags.

Comment: I noticed that, so I appended the standards to the flag. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not use `add_definitions` for that, instead do something like

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c99")
```

`-std=c99` if you want loop initial declarations.

`add_definitions` is for definitions like `-DUSE_SOME_LIBRARY`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `add_definitions` you should use something like this instead:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++0x")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first test if the compiler supports C++11, see check_cxx_compiler_flag included in the macro CheckCXXCompilerFlag